# Why do I see such different rafter span tables for open beam ceilings?

Tags: framing, ceiling, roof, load

Considering an open-beamed ceiling in southern california.

Span is roughly 12'6" long ... perhaps 3-in-10 slope.

I would like to use 4x8 rafters every 48 inches.  However, this table from Escondido:

https://www.escondido.org/Data/Sites/1/media/pdfs/Building/InfoGuideline17.pdf

... seems to suggest that 11'6" is the longest allowed span for 4x8s 48" OC.

Looking further, I see another municipality:

https://poway.org/DocumentCenter/View/249/Span-Tables-PDF

... lists 14'6" as the max allowable span for 4x8 rafter.

That's a very large difference between those two code regimes.  I wonder two things:

1. Very generally speaking, not just in California, what's a reasonable max span for a 4x8 roof rafter ?  No snow, but we plan on plywood shear + 2x layers of 3.5" OSB-backed foam board (to achieve r30) and then metal roof on top ... so we might need 30 psf load, not 20 ?
2. Why are these two numbers so different ?

Thank you.

Comment: Without delving into the documents - apart from snow load there's also species and grade of the timber, and possibly (given California) seismic hazard "zone" differences.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the first, shorter span case does not appear to specify that it's "for supporting the roof only" as the second case does, explicitly, with explicit very light loads and generous deflection. The first case seems to specify design loads and deflections for the lighter lumber as joist or rafter and then says nothing for the open beam case, unless I'm being blind.

This [wood beam calculator](https://jonochshorn.com/scholarship/calculators-st/example8.1/index.html) can be handy for reference but what your locality wants will rule - and you will have to understand what your design loads really are to make good use of it.

Answer (score 1):

There’s lots of factors that determine the size of wood beams. Wood is somewhat elastic, so it depends on how many allowable factors you care to investigate to determine its maximum span.

1. Even the same grade and species can have its “allowable stresses” increased based on “duration of load.” That is to say that if you put a heavy short duration load on a beam it will act the same as a smaller long term load. Snow loads less than 1 month is classic. (Some tables skip this calculation.)
2. Grade of beam can be upgraded if more of the beam (edges of beam) can be observed during grading. That’s why carpenters like to hand pick beams, (they know they have an extra safety factor so the beams won’t twist, Bend, etc.)
3. Beams are calculated using the “working stress design” or “ultimate stress design”. Working stress leaves a BIG safety factor because they know a home owner will be using it. Ultimate stress design figures exactly when the beam will fail and then uses an allowable safety factor...sometimes 1.5, or 1.8%.

I like a very safe size rather than figuring everything too tight. You never know when the client will call and want to add an air conditioner on the roof, or they’re going to invite you to their 50th anniversary out on their deck. (I sleep well that way.)

Comment: Did you really mean to say 1.8%?  Shouldn't that be a factor of 1.5 or 1.8, which would be 50% or 80% for the safety factor.  At least that's what I've seen in stress calculations.

Comment: @SteveSh Yes, sorry for the confusion.